Fit video references to the same size as my camera. Both is 16:9 ratio
I work in 16:9 and have a video that I use as a reference behind my 3D object. Is there a way to get the video reference to be exactly the size of the camera I have?

You can set the camera to have the same aspect ratio as your video. Are you talking about putting the video into the Video Sequencer or the 3D viewport?

Both is 16:9 ratio already. But when I import the video its huge. I want it to scale it exactly. Its in the 3D viewport! :)

take a look at this https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/315325/show-texture-preview-via-gpu-module/315572#315572 where i create a camera that exactly fits on top of the plane. you just have to adjust RESOLUTION to RESOLUTION_X and Y

That looked interesting! However, I've never worked with Python. Is there an easy way to understand how to get started?
